Do you re-include system headers in the implementation files?
Here's a scenario:
suppose you have #include <unordered_map> in the header
and you don't declare it anywhere in the implementation file
but you use it, maybe
mp[whatever] = some;

should you re-include the <unordered_map> header? what is best practice?
in general, what's the best practice w.r.t relying on transitive includes like this, assuming that those things you are relying on are perhaps part of the method type signatures or member variables?
to be more explicit:
std::unordered_map<>

might occur in the header
but no way does the type appear in the implementation. An object of that type is only used.

Does this answer your question? Is it good practice to rely on headers being included transitively?

Does this answer your question? Is it good practice to rely on headers being included transitively?

@BartvanIngenSchenau: did you notice that the other question (and its answers) does not say anything about sys-lib headers? All examples shown there are about project-immanent headers. I was considering to vote as a dupe, too, but I hesitated exactky because of this difference.

@DocBrown, that difference is inconsequential.

I'm not asking that question here. You don't know what mp[whatever] = some is. Only by looking into the header, would you know what it is. It could be anything that implements the [] operator. I'm asking specifically for cases where a declaration of that type doesn't occur in the implementation file, but it is used there.

@BartvanIngenSchenau: please read my answer below and tell me which answer in that other question thread explains it.

@DocBrown, your answer is good (+1), but I believe the answers on the other question also apply. There is no fundamental difference between including <unordered_map> or "Texture.hpp".

@BartvanIngenSchenau: there is a difference - headers from standard libs don't change (or at least very rarely), so the negative effect of transitive includes to build times will less matter than in the case of project-immanent headers. This might be irrelevant for this case, but I think it is not necessarily obvious for the asker that this is the case. That other question is related, of course, but Ben Cotrell's comment seems to be enough for my taste - I would not have close-voted this as a dupe.

When

a header file A.h requires an include for <unordered_map>, and

the related cpp file A.cpp (which includes A.h) contains some code dealing with objects of type unordered_map (regardless whether that type is written explicitly in the cpp or not)


there is no clear consensus in the C++ community whether A.cpp should include <unordered_map> as well or not.
Source: David Kieras,, C++ Header File Guidelines (2015), see page 3, Guideline #12. That paper also explains the two possible point of views, either

the two includes are redundant, or

readability should be favored over redundancy in this case


IMHO both POV can be justified. I would recommend to pick one of the two conventions and stick to it throughout your code base.

Thank you. What was the thing you mentioned in your comment about it being a system header and transitive not affecting build time once? I’m not sure what transitivity has anything to do with build times, given the inclusion is handled by the preprocessor.

And the preprocessor doesn’t take any time?

@user129393192: in C++, when you don't follow a few restricting rules in regards to header files and includes (they are mentioned in the paper I linked to), you can easily end up with one little change in the wrong header file causing a cascade of files which need to be recompiled and relinked. In a small program, this won't matter, but in a program with >1000 classes (each one with a header and a cpp file) this can cause build timesof several minutes, if not hours.
